# Improvements To Login Form In 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I've made a code to as a final project in school... It's a login form.
It can register and login but the only bug I've found is that I can't enter a password with 16 digits.

Please give me feedback on what could I fix or make better at the program.

Thanks in advance.

```
 .MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.DATA
 uinp db 13, 0, 14 DUP('$')  ; Username register input, max 12 letters                    ;
 pinp db 17, 0, 16 DUP('$')  ; Password register input, max 16 letters

 ulinp db 13, 0, 14 DUP('$') ; Username login input
 plinp db 17, 0, 16 DUP('$') ; Password login input

 wlmsg db "        Welcome user!        ", 10, 13, "$"      ;     
 wlmsg2 db "        Please login...        ", 10, 13, "$"   ; Welcome messages
 wlmsg3 db "        Press any key..        ", 10, 13, "$"   ;

 umsg db "        Username:         ", 10, 13,       ;
 db "        Password:         $", 10, 13,       ; Username and password text

 question db "        Would you like to               ", 10, 13   ;
     db   "        (R) Register               ", 10, 13      ; Main menu text
     db   "        (L) Login               ", 10, 13         ;
     db   "           ( )               $", 10, 13           ;

 errormsg db "           ERROR!        ", 10, 13          ;
  db "     Please make sure you        ", 10, 13     ;
  db "   followed the instructions        ", 10, 13  ;   Error message                ; JUST TO CLARIFY:
  db "     and wrote your choice        ", 10, 13    ;                                ; At first I wanted to create a file, write the username and password onto it 
  db "      with CAPITAL LETTERS        $", 10, 13   ;                                ; and then read it. Turn's out that it was out of the course scope and it's not
                                                                                      ; critical for the program.  

 errormsg2 db "     username or password are incorrect ", 10, 13      ; Second error message
      db "            try again later... $"

 afterRegisterMsg db "        Nice, now go back to menu $", 10, 13    ; After registration message

 sLogin db "                                    ", 10, 13 
   db "        ********************************* ", 10, 13
   db "        *You have succesfully logged in!* ", 10, 13 ; Message after      succesful match to the user name and password 
   db "        *********************************$", 10, 13
 choice db ' '      ;o Choice of user in menu    

 fLogin db "       Username and password are incorrect.",10 ,13   ; Fail to login message
   db "        Please try again and make sure", 10, 13
   db "         enterd the right username and", 10, 13
   db "                   password.         $", 10, 13

 .CODE                                                        

mov ax, @data                   
mov ds, ax                                   


 Welcome:
mov dx, offset wlmsg   ; First message
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov dx, offset wlmsg2  ; Second message
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov dx, offset wlmsg3 ; Third message
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov ah, 01h   ; Wait for user to continue
int 21h       ;

call clear    ; Clear screen


 Menu:
call clear              ; Clear screen

mov dx, offset question ;
mov ah, 09h             ;  Print menu
int 21h                 ;

mov dh, 03h        ;
mov dl, 12         ;
mov bh, 0          ; Set cursor to (12,3)
mov ah, 02h        ; 
int 10h

mov ah, 01h             ; 
int 21h                 ; Reads user's choice         


cmp al, 'R'    ;  Check if user picked register option

je Register           ; Jump to 1register label

cmp al, 'L'    ;  Check if user picked login option

je Login             ; Jump to login label
jmp Error 


 Error:
call clear

mov dx, offset errormsg  ;
mov ah, 09h              ;  Print error message
int 21h                  ; 

mov ah, 08h   ; Wait for user to continue
int 21h       ;


 jmp Menu                 ; Jump back to menu


 Register:
call clear           ; Clear screen

mov dx, offset umsg  ;
mov ah, 09h          ; Print username 
int 21h              ;           

mov dx, 18        ;
mov bh, 0         ; Set cursor to (18,0)
mov ah, 02h       ; 
int 10h

mov dx, offset uinp ;
mov ah, 0Ah         ; Read username input and puts it into uinp
int 21h             ;

mov dh, 01h       ;
mov dl, 18        ;
mov bh, 0         ; Set cursor to (18,1)
mov ah, 02h       ; 
int 10h

mov dx, offset pinp     ;
mov ah, 0Ah             ; Reads password input and puts it into pinp
int 21h                 ;

call clear

mov dx, offset afterRegisterMsg    ;
mov ah, 09h                        ;  Print after registration message
int 21h                            ;

mov ah, 01h                        ; Waits for user to click a button
int 21h                            ;

jmp menu                     ; Go back to menu

 Login: 
call clear               ; Clear screen

mov dx, offset umsg    ;
mov ah, 09h            ;   Prints username and password
int 21h                ;

mov dx, 18        ;
mov bh, 0         ; Set cursor to (18,0)
mov ah, 02h       ; 
int 10h

mov dx, offset ulinp  ;
mov ah, 0Ah           ;   Reads username login input 
int 21h               ;

mov dh, 01h       ;
mov dl, 18        ;
mov bh, 0         ; Set cursor to (18,1)
mov ah, 02h       ; 
int 10h

mov dx, offset plinp  ;
mov ah, 0Ah           ;   Reads password login input 
int 21h               ;

call chkLength ; Match length

mov dx, 0      ;
mov cx, 0      ;  Reset all the registers for compUser
mov ax, 0      ;

jmp CompareU  ; Check if username is correct 

 hlt


 chkLength:           ;

mov dh, [uinp + 1]   ; Finding the length of the username that the user have enterd
mov dl, [ulinp + 1]  ; "                                     "                    "

cmp dh, dl           ; Comparing their lengths

jne Error2           ; If their lengths aren't equal there will be an error

mov dh, [pinp + 1]   ; Finding the length of the password that the user have enterd
mov dl, [plinp + 1]  ; "                                     "                    "

cmp dh, dl           ; Comparing their lengths

jne Error2           ; Error if the strings don't have the same lengths

ret                  ; Go back to the login main


 Error2:             ; After comparing error

call clear      ; call clear

mov dx, offset errormsg2     ;
mov ah, 09h                  ; Error in case the user entered wrong username and password
int 21h                      ; 

mov ah, 01h     ; Wait for click
int 21h         ;

call clear      ; Clear screen
int 20h         ; End the program          


 CompareU:           ; Comparing the usernames 

mov dh, offset uinp ; Get uinp address
add dh, 2       ; Add 2 to skip to the actaul string

mov dl, offset ulinp  ; Get ulinp address
add dl, 2       ; Add 2 to skip to the actaul string

add dh, cl      ; Adding the index to the address so it can know what character to go through
add dl, cl      ; "                                                                         "

push cx         ; Maintaining the index count

mov bh, 0       ;
mov bl, dh      ; Going into the memory to get uinp actaul string
mov ch, [bx]    ;

mov bh, 0       ;
mov bl, dl      ; Going into the memory to get ulinp actaul string
mov cl, [bx]    ;

cmp cl, ch      ; Comparing the two usernames     

jne Error2      ; If the usernames are not the same it sum as an error

mov bh, 0       ; 
mov bl, dh      ; 
mov al, [bx]    ; Cheking if the string ended
cmp al, '$'     ; 

je resetReg     ; Reset all the registers for the password compare

pop cx          ; Pop the index back out again so it could be increased

inc cl          ; Increase the index by 1 to go over the next charachter 

jmp CompareU    ; Jump back again to the head of the label to check all over again


 resetReg:           ; Reset registers label 

mov ax, 0       ; Reset ax
mov bx, 0       ; Reset bx
mov cx, 0       ; Reset cx
mov dx, 0       ; Reset dx

jmp CompareP    ; Go to the password comparing


 CompareP:           ; Comparing the passwords

mov dh, offset pinp    ; Get pinp address
add dh, 2       ; Add 2 to skip to the actaul string

mov dl, offset plinp   ; Get plinp address
add dl, 2       ; Add 2 to skip to the actaul string

add dh, cl      ; Adding the index to the address so it can know what character to go through
add dl, cl      ; "                                                                         "

push cx         ; Maintaining the index count

mov bh, 0       ;
mov bl, dh      ; Going into the memory to get pinp actaul string
mov ch, [bx]    ;

mov bh, 0       ;
mov bl, dl      ; Going into the memory to get plinp actaul string
mov cl, [bx]    ;

cmp cl, ch      ; Comparing the two passwords     

jne Error2      ; If the passwords are not the same it sum as an error

mov bh, 0       ;
mov bl, dh      ;
mov al, [bx]    ; Cheking if the string ended
cmp al, '$'     ;

je successLogin ; Letting the user know that he enterd and both username and password are true

pop cx          ; Pop the index back out again so it could be increased

inc cl          ; Increase the index by 1 to go over the next charachter
jmp CompareP    ; Jump back again to the head of the label to check all over again

 successLogin:       ; Successful login message

call clear      ; Clearing the screen

mov dx, offset sLogin     ; 
mov ah, 09h               ;  Print the successful login message
int 21h                   ;

mov ah, 01h     ; Waiting for the user to make it's final click
int 21h         ;

 int 20h             ; End of the program in case the login was succesful 

 clear:
mov ah, 06h       ;
mov al, 00h       ;
mov bh, 0Fh       ;
mov cx, 0         ; Clear Screen
mov dh, 100       ;
mov dl, 40        ;
int 10h           ;

mov dx, 0         ;
mov bh, 0         ; Set cursor to (0,0)
mov ah, 02h       ; 
int 10h 

ret               ; Return back to where it was called

 int 20h             ; End of program no matter what
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried debugging? If not, please do. Trace it step by step, watch register values. Which line acts differently from what you were expecting?

Comment: If this works and you're asking for a code review, there's a [codereview.SE] site for that.  For this to be a good question over there, you still need to give more high-level description of what it's *supposed* to do.  I just see a giant block of code (with lots of good low-level comments describing what's happening locally), but IDK what the overall design is or even what the original problem statement was, let alone what tradeoffs you considered while writing it.  e.g. what are the inputs/outputs and data structures.  Describe some of that in English as well as just showing code.

Answer (score 2):

> but the only bug I've found is that I can't enter a password with 16 digits.

The structures that you use to input the passwords use an inconsistent setting. You've declared the buffer longer than the buffer that you provide!

```
uinp db 13, 0, 14 DUP('$')  ; Username register input, max 12 letters                    ;
pinp db 17, 0, 16 DUP('$')  ; Password register input, max 16 letters

ulinp db 13, 0, 14 DUP('$') ; Username login input
plinp db 17, 0, 16 DUP('$') ; Password login input
```

Both lines for the username are fine, but the lines for the password should be using `18 DUP('$')` in stead of `16 DUP('$')`.

A further consideration is that DOS will need 2 bytes for each *extended character* that you want included in the password. (not uncommon in a password) Perhaps you could guard against this by writing:

```
pinp db 17, 0, 35 DUP('$')  ; Password register input, max 16 letters
plinp db 17, 0, 35 DUP('$') ; Password login input
```

---

There are a few places in your program where you write:

```
mov dh, offset uinp ; Get uinp address
add dh, 2       ; Add 2 to skip to the actaul string

mov dl, offset ulinp  ; Get ulinp address
add dl, 2       ; Add 2 to skip to the actaul string
```

This is a **very dangerous** construct!
In your current program it works *because the structures involved are placed early in the .DATA section* meaning the high byte of the offset address will be zero. Consider what would happen if these input structures were placed below all of the other messages. Havoc for sure!
I suggest you use the full 16-bit value given by the OFFSET operator.

```
 CompareU:           ; Comparing the usernames 

mov di, offset uinp ; Get uinp address
add di, 2       ; Add 2 to skip to the actaul string

mov si, offset ulinp  ; Get ulinp address
add si, 2       ; Add 2 to skip to the actaul string

add di, cx      ; Adding the index to the address so it can know what character to go through
add si, cx      ; "                                                                         "

push cx         ; Maintaining the index count

mov ch, [di]    ;
mov cl, [si]    ;
cmp cl, ch      ; Comparing the two usernames     
jne Error2      ; If the usernames are not the same it sum as an error

cmp ch, '$'     ; Cheking if the string ended
je resetReg     ; Reset all the registers for the password compare

pop cx          ; Pop the index back out again so it could be increased

inc cx          ; Increase the index by 1 to go over the next charachter 

jmp CompareU    ; Jump back again to the head of the label to check all over again
```

In the previous code I only focussed on the word-size replacement but it has other issues.

Look what happens when the string end is found. You jump away to the *resetReg* label but the stack still holds a CX value that wasn't `pop`-ed. The solution here is to place the `pop cx` instruction between the `cmp` and `je` instructions. You *can* do this because the `pop` instruction doesn't modify any of the flags. Jumping to the *Error2* label is not problematic because then the program ends anyway.

```
cmp ch, '$'     ; Cheking if the string ended
pop cx          ; Pop the index back out again so it could be increased
je resetReg     ; Reset all the registers for the password compare
```

All of the above also applies to the *CompareP* routine.

---

There are a good number of opportunities here to optimize the code.
I'll show just 1 because ultimately that's not what StackOverflow is about!

```
mov ch, [di]    ;
mov cl, [si]    ;
cmp cl, ch      ; Comparing the two usernames
```

You can compare straight from memory in stead of transferring to the CL register:

```
mov ch, [di]    ;
cmp [si], ch    ; Comparing the two usernames
```